# LWJGL Inventory Rendering Wrong

Tags: java, opengl, 2d, lwjgl

So ive been working on a 2D rpg game and ive worked out the inventory quite nicely but ive ran into a problem where when I have an item in a slot the slot directly after it doesnt render; its just a black square.

Here is a visual: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OypGj.jpg

Im using immediate mode rendering.

Rendering inventory method:

```
 public void render(Renderer renderer) {
    if (shown == false) {
        return;
    }
    //renderer.renderRectangle(0, x, y, 220, 240, Color4f.BLACK);
    renderer.setFont(font);
    renderer.renderString("Inventory", x + 24, y + 11, Color4f.WHITE);
    renderer.setFont(Renderer.DEFAULT_FONT);

    int drawSlotsX = x + 25;
    int drawSlotsY = y + 50;

    int xPos = 0;
    int yPos = 0;
    int maxX = 4;
    int maxY = 4;



    for (int i = 0; i < slots.length; i++) {

        int renderX = ((xPos * 32) + drawSlotsX) + 2 * xPos;
        int renderY = ((yPos * 32) + drawSlotsY) + 2 * yPos;

        renderer.renderTexture(slot, renderX, renderY, 32, 32, 0);


        if (collisionBoxs[i] == null) {
            collisionBoxs[i] = new Rectangle(renderX, renderY, 32, 32);
        }
        if (slots[i] != null) { 
            renderer.renderTexture(slots[i].getItem().getIcon().getIcon(), renderX, renderY, 24, 32, 0);


            if (slots[i].getAmount() < 10) {
                renderer.renderString("" + slots[i].getAmount(), renderX + 22, renderY + 18, Color4f.BLACK);
            } else {
                renderer.renderString("" + slots[i].getAmount(), renderX + 18, renderY + 18, Color4f.BLACK);
            }
        }

        if (xPos < maxX) {
            xPos++;
        } else {
            xPos = 0;
            if (yPos < maxY) {
                yPos++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (grabbedItem != null) {
        renderer.renderTexture(grabbedItem.getItem().getIcon().getIcon(),  Mouse.getX(), (Engine.FRAME_HEIGHT - Mouse.getY()),  32, 32, 0);
    }
}
```

Sorry if you cant see the problem within this method!

Comment: Looks to me like your color setting from the font rendering is leaking (i.e. you don't set the color again before rendering the next rectangle). You can check if that's it by doing `org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);` after the `renderer.renderString(` and seeing if that changes the rectangle to red

Comment: That was it mate! I simply added a "glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);" after i rendered the string and it worked perfectly! Thanks!